# Calculating output voltage of a boost converter circuit

Tags: capacitor, converter, coil, resonant-converter

This a problem with a circuit of an up-converter, consisting of a constant voltage supply (E), a switch (SW), a diode (D), a coil (L), a capacitor (C), and terminals as shown in the figure.

i(0) = 0 and v(0) = E.

The switch is shorted from t = 0 to T0, then opened until T1 with i(T0+T1) = 0. This operation is repeated n times.

The goal is to find v(n(T0+T1)).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fESVAX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

From here is my own understanding, I might have missed something.
From t=0 to T0, we have E = L di/dt so i(t) = E/L t;
i(T0) = E/L T0

From T0 to T1, we have the equation,
$$E = L \frac{di}{dt} + \frac{1}{C}\int{i dt}$$

By taking LaPlace transform
$$\frac{E}{s} = Ls I(s) + \frac{1}{Cs} I(s) - \frac{1}{C} i(T_0)$$

Yielding after reverse transform,
$$i(t) = \frac{E\sqrt{LC}}{L}sin(\sqrt{LC}t) + \frac{i(T_0)}{LC}cos(\sqrt{LC}t)$$

Then
$$ T_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}(-\alpha + \pi/2)$$ with  $$ \alpha = tan^{-1}(\frac{\frac{E}{L}\sqrt{LC}}{\frac{T_0}{L^2C}})$$

There is an intermediary question, that asks to prove i(n(T0+T1))=0. I am not sure about this but it can be done using mathematical induction on n.
$$for\ n(T_0+T_1)<t<n(T_0+T_1) +T_0:\ \ \ i(n(T_0+T_1)+T_0)=\frac{E}{L}T_0$$
$$for\ n(T_0+T_1)+T_0<t<n(T_0+T_1) +T_0+T_1: \ \ \ i((n+1)(T_0+T_1))=0$$
As for the v(n(T0+T1))
I think for n=1, we can just take the
$$v(T_0+T_1) = \frac{1}{C}\int_{0}^{T_1}i(t)dt =  \frac{1}{C}\int_{0}^{T_1}Acos(\sqrt{LC}t+\alpha)dt $$

Comment: Are you purposely trying to solve this by using a non-conventional approach or, is it just pure naivety/ignorance that you decided on this (suspiciously flawed) approach?

Comment: I should have added I am a bit far from the field

Comment: [My approach](http://www.stades.co.uk/Boost%20converter/Boost%20calculator.html) - but, considering you are just interested in the boundary condition (inductor current falls to zero then the cycle immediately repeats) it's a lot easier and V = Ldi/dt means that the output voltage is also defined by the slope of di/dt during the period T0 to T1.

Comment: An "up-converter" is a frequency converter where Fout > Fin (usually part of a radio system). I believe you are asking about a boost converter where you want Vout > Vin. Using the right term when you search for information will get you better results.

Comment: Replying to Andy, [boost converter](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/discontinuous-conduction-mode-of-simple-converters/)  shows that energy at the start and at the end of the cycle is the same so we can use volt-time balance equation. Which seems to yield V=( 1-T0/(T1-T0) ) E. Is that correct? And also is constant?

Comment: That site is for discontinuous operation. You have boundary or continuous operation. I left you a valid link.

Answer (score 0):

> *The switch is shorted from t = 0 to T0, then opened until T1 with
> i(T0+T1) = 0. This operation is repeated n times.*

You are operating at the boundary condition (and you need an appropriate load for this to remain so). Try reading this on the link I gave earlier: -

[image]

> *Calculating output voltage of a boost converter circuit*

$$V_{OUT} = V_{IN}\cdot \dfrac{1}{1-D}$$

This requires that the output load be appropriately sized i.e. it perfectly consumes all the power supplied by the inductor in each switching cycle.